# ImageView vs Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-imageview

Are the ImageView class and Canvas class completely different ways to draw things or are they related? Also, what are the pros and cons to using each of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing `View` and `Canvas` is comparing apples and oranges. Anything that goes onto the screen is in a `View`. A `Canvas` just provides a way to draw things; it's used internally by all `View` types, including `ImageView`. If you implement a custom `View` type, a `Canvas` is the argument to `onDraw()` with which you can do your custom drawing. A `Canvas` can also be used to draw into an off-screen `Bitmap` object, but you still need to use some sort of `View` object to get it to the screen. If you're familiar with Java's AWT or Swing, think of Android's `Canvas` class as similar to J2SE's `Graphics` class.

For more information about how all this works, check out the Android developer guide topic [Canvas and Drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html).

Comment: Ok so a canvas is the argument to the onDraw method, so say you have a blank canvas and draw something on it. Then you want to add on to it. So if you pass the drawn-on canvas as an argument, when you draw another thing, both drawing will show up?

Comment: @Sygnerical - No. The `Canvas` object itself does not contain any image information. It is simply the conduit for drawing onto some other object (e.g., a `View` or a `Bitmap`). The class name was, I think, poorly chosen; an instance of the class is not a "canvas" in the every-day sense of a drawing surface. If you have a custom `View` class, you need to draw everything that you want to appear in the view on each call to `onDraw()`. Please read the guide documentation. A `SurfaceView` may be closer to what you are thinking about.

Comment: I'm looking for the best way to draw things that have to constantly change in size and existence (deleting shapes, spawning shapes). What do you think is the best class for that, SurfaceView?

Comment: I read over the Canvas and Drawables link, SurfaceView does look like the best option.

Comment: @Sygnerical - Yes, I think that's probably what you are looking for, particularly if you are doing animation rather than redrawing based on user-generated events.

Answer (score 0):

AN ImageView is a view that holds a bitmap object.  You do not draw to it at all.  It's just a bitmap on screen.

A canvas is a low level drawing abstraction-  its a place you can draw to.  You can do any type of drawing there-  lines, images text, etc.  Its what you use if you want to draw a complex view from scratch, or draw to make an in memory bitmap.

Comment: On canvas, can you draw something then come back to it later to add on or change something?

Comment: If you back it to an in memory bitmap, yes.  But you'd be drawing over those pixels, there's no undo

Comment: But you can't erase any of it like if you wanted to make it smaller or disappear?